# Colorblind aware Red and Blue

Tags: data-visualization, ggplot2

When plottling discrete data I tend to use some colorblind palette, even though I am not affected myself. Now I want to plot hearing test data. There is a general (i.e., international) understanding, that hearing tests data gained on a right ear are colored red and data gained on a left ear are colored blue. Usually on white paper/background.

So I am looking for a red and a blue color that are especially colorblind friendly. (Better yet, light and dark reds and blues?)

Obviously I could just find any of many colorblind friendly palettes on the web ([like those in ggpubfigs](https://github.com/JLSteenwyk/ggpubfigs)) and choose a red and a blue from one of those (but which, if there are [so many to choose from](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorBlindness/vignettes/colorBlindness.html#How_to_use_this_package)). However, I assume those do compromise at points and as I want to include the choice in [the audiometry package on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=audiometry) I would like to somewhat optimize the choice for red and blue.

Any ideas or even personal insights of those affected on how to proceed? Is there reliable data on which colorblind palettes work better worse?

In my understanding this a question about how to communicate a specific type of data and statistical results and should therefore be on topic on CV.

Comment: There are many different forms of "color blindness" and the suitability of any palette depends on them. Moreover, changing these colors will to some extent "compromise" the palette for ordinarily-sighted people. Thus, some kind of trade-off will be made. To solve this problem, then, we need to know (a) how to quantify the amount of "compromise" and (b) how much to weight each form of color perception in our objective function.  Consequently, this question looks unlikely to have a unique solution.  Since red and blue are easily distinguishable by all but very rare monochromats, why bother?

Comment: Could you use two different marker, line or fill styles as well as the colouring? This has the additional benefit that if your figure is reproduced in black and white, the two groups will still be distinguishable.

Comment: @whuber I also assume, there is no unique best solution but that does not imply that there are no pitfalls or best practices to follow and no best answer to this question.

Comment: @8e9yQBKVlIDwoIVegfkJ Off course we should always strive to make our plots as unmistakeble as possible. For example, there is also a (less strict) convention on which shapes to use. I have no questions on shapes and line types right now. However, if users of my package want to follow the established color coding of their field, I want to help them in doing so.

Comment: A personal favourite is [Paul Tol's colour schemes](https://personal.sron.nl/~pault/), they are implemented in R within `khroma`. There's a section on colour blindness (usually having trouble distinguishing reds/greens) in the link.